# css image won't show up

Tags: html, css

I want to do a responsive design and it would be easier to add 2 different images in CSS then HTMl, but the image won't show, tried sizes and different styles, moved the image from image folder to the html css folder, nothing works, here is my code:

```
                * {
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                  }

                main {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                background-color: var(--main-background);
                position: relative;
                 }

               .card {
               display: flex;
               flex-direction: column;
               width: 200px;
               height: 400px;
               background-color: var(--card-background);
               position: absolute;
               top: 50%;
               left: 50%;
               transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
               }

               .image {
               background-image: url(./image-header-mobile.jpg);
               width: 100%;
               }



               <body>
                 <main>
                  <section class="card">
                   <div class="image"></div>
                   <div class="info"></div>
                  </section>
                 </main>
               </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `height: 100%;` to your `.image` CSS.

Because your div is empty, the image isn't shown. Your div doesn't have any height.

```css
.image {
  background-image: url("image.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "" in the start and the end of the picture path
Like this :

```
background-image: url("./image-header-mobile.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `div`, you need to give it **width** and **height**.

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('xxx.png');
}
```